# drop shadow for png images in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a non-shaped png image that with this

```
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #575757);
filter:         drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #575757);
```

I can add shadow to images but just in Chrome.
How can I add shadow in IE?

Answer (score 1):

With this MS filter ?

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=5, OffY=5, Color='#575757')";
filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=5, OffY=5, Color='#575757')";
```

Comment: This only works up to IE 9. Version 10+ dropped support for this.

Answer (score 1):

Drop-shadow is working on 9+ IE versions. if you have 9+IE installed on your system you can use following code for drop shadow of image or div or text(for text use text instead of box).

```
#img
{ 
   box-shadow:5px 5px 5px #000; 
   -moz- box-shadow:5px 5px 5px #000;//for mozilla 
   -webkit - box-shadow:5px 5px 5px #000;//for chrome 
   -o- box-shadow:5px 5px 5px #000;//for opera 
   -ms- box-shadow:5px 5px 5px #000; //for IE 
}
```

Comment: It is not the same a box-shadow than a drop-shadow filter, specially if the png has transparency applied. See http://bricss.net/post/33158273857/box-shadow-vs-filter-drop-shadow